# Shortest path on a topological graph with default weight

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

Using neo4j (with APOC 5.7), I'm trying to find the shortest path on a topological graph (no location on the nodes), where the weight of each step is 1 by default. I don't want to limit the number of steps for the path, only the relationship type.

The [documentation](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/algorithms/path-finding-procedures/) is very flat:

`apoc.algo.dijkstra` requires a weight on the relationship

`apoc.algo.dijkstraWithDefaultWeight` throws: `There is no procedure with the name apoc.algo.dijkstraWithDefaultWeight`

`apoc.algo.aStar` and `apoc.algo.aStarWithPoint` require points location or `lat` and `long`

`apoc.algo.allSimplePaths` requires `maxNodes` and is a full graph search...

For example, for the graph:

```
CREATE (b:City {name:'Berlin'})
CREATE (m:City {name:'München'})
CREATE (f:City {name:'Frankfurt'})
CREATE (h:City {name:'Hamburg'})
MERGE (b)-[:DIRECT]-(h)
MERGE (b)-[:DIRECT]-(m)
MERGE (b)-[:DIRECT]-(f)
MERGE (f)-[:DIRECT]-(m)
MERGE (f)-[:DIRECT]-(h)
```

I would like the get something like:

```
╒════════╤══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│weight  │path                                                                  │
╞════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│2.0     │(:City {name: "München"})<-[:DIRECT]-(:City {name: "Frankfurt"})-     |
│        │[:DIRECT]->(:City {name: "Hamburg"})                                  │       
└────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Currently, the simplest option I see is to use `apoc.algo.dijkstra` and add a `weight` property with a value `1` on each relationship - which is absurd.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the weight you may not have to use APOC at all, but instead the built-in Cypher shortestPath function:

```
MATCH path=shortestPath((:City {name: 'München'})-[d:DIRECT*]-(:City {name: 'Hamburg'})) RETURN size(d) AS weight, path
```

which gives this result

```
╒══════╤══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│weight│path                                                                  │
╞══════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│2     │(:City {name: "München"})<-[:DIRECT]-(:City {name: "Frankfurt"})-[:DIR│
│      │ECT]->(:City {name: "Hamburg"})                                       │
└──────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Interesting. Will try it and validate

Comment: You may need to impose an upper bound (e.g., `*..7`) on the variable-length relationship to avoid taking too long or running out of memory.